# Left Join with an Inner Join - can't seem to get the syntax correct

Tags: sql, left-join, inner-join

I am working with a HP NonStop Tandem database.  I am trying to write a query to pull back production information and to include purchase order information if it exists.  The problem I am having is when data does not exist or match the criteria.  Also, the purchase order information is on two different tables - a header and a detail table.  I need to match the product to the detail table, get the po number then return the header information but only if the po status on the header is less than 40.

I have tried several variations of the query, but cannot seem to get it correct.

The closest I have gotten is below, but it will return the E.CASES_RECEIVED even when the LEFT OUTER JOIN PO_HEADER F does not meet the criteria.

```
 SELECT A.DISTRICT,
        A.PRODUCT_NUMBER,
        A.PRODUCT_DESC_LONG,
        B.UNITS_ON_HAND,
        E.CASES_RECEIVED,
        F.PO_NUMBER,
        F.PO_STATUS,
        F.SCHED_ARRIVAL_DATE
 FROM PRODUCT A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN WAREHOUSE B
     ON A.PRODUCT_NUMBER = B.PRODUCT_NUMBER 
   AND A.DISTRICT = B.DISTRICT 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN PO_DETAIL E
      ON A.PRODUCT_NUMBER = E.PRODUCT_NUMBER 
    AND A.DISTRICT = E.DISTRICT 
        AND E.PO_NUMBER > 899999999

  LEFT OUTER JOIN PO_HEADER F
             ON E.PO_NUMBER = F.PO_NUMBER 
             AND E.DISTRICT = F.DISTRICT 
                AND F.PO_NUMBER > 899999999
            AND F.PO_STATUS < '40' 
          WHERE A.DISTRICT = 2170 
            AND A.PRODUCT_NUMBER = 6849452
 ;
```

When I try below, it works as a where clause and then I return nothing when there is no PO:

```
 SELECT A.DISTRICT,
        A.PRODUCT_NUMBER,
        A.PRODUCT_DESC_LONG,
        B.UNITS_ON_HAND,
        E.CASES_RECEIVED,
        F.PO_NUMBER,
        F.PO_STATUS,
        F.SCHED_ARRIVAL_DATE
   FROM PRODUCT A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN WAREHOUSE B
     ON A.PRODUCT_NUMBER = B.PRODUCT_NUMBER 
   AND A.DISTRICT = B.DISTRICT 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN PO_DETAIL E
      ON A.PRODUCT_NUMBER = E.PRODUCT_NUMBER 
    AND A.DISTRICT = E.DISTRICT 
        AND E.PO_NUMBER > 899999999
  INNER JOIN PO_HEADER F
             ON E.PO_NUMBER = F.PO_NUMBER 
             AND E.DISTRICT = F.DISTRICT 
            AND F.PO_NUMBER > 899999999
            AND F.PO_STATUS < '40' 
  WHERE A.DISTRICT = 2170 
    AND A.PRODUCT_NUMBER = 6849452
 ;
```

I have tried this query but get an error due to the brackets for the INNER join:

```
 SELECT A.DISTRICT,
        A.PRODUCT_NUMBER,
        A.PRODUCT_DESC_LONG,
        B.UNITS_ON_HAND,
        E.CASES_RECEIVED,
        F.PO_NUMBER,
        F.PO_STATUS,
        F.SCHED_ARRIVAL_DATE
   FROM PRODUCT A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN WAREHOUSE B
     ON A.PRODUCT_NUMBER = B.PRODUCT_NUMBER 
   AND A.DISTRICT = B.DISTRICT 
  LEFT JOIN (PO_DETAIL E
         INNER JOIN PO_HEADER F
             ON F.PO_NUMBER = E.PO_NUMBER 
            AND F.PO_NUMBER > 899999999
            AND F.PO_STATUS < '40' )
      ON A.PRODUCT_NUMBER = E.PRODUCT_NUMBER = 
     AND A.DISTRICT = E.DISTRICT 
     AND E.PO_NUMBER > 899999999
WHERE A.DISTRICT = 2170 
  AND A.PRODUCT_NUMBER = 6849452
 ;
```

Any assistance on how to get the query to work, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What RMDBS are you on? MSSQL, MYSQL, etc,. Also, are you able to post the table column definitions? That, along with sample data would make it much easier to solve.

Comment: You can create a DERIVED table and join to it... had to shorten it -- SELECT *
   FROM PRODUCT A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN WAREHOUSE B
     ON A.PRODUCT_NUMBER = B.PRODUCT_NUMBER 
   AND A.DISTRICT = B.DISTRICT 
  LEFT JOIN (
  select * from 
  PO_DETAIL E
         INNER JOIN PO_HEADER F
             ON F.PO_NUMBER = E.PO_NUMBER 
            AND F.PO_NUMBER > 899999999
            AND F.PO_STATUS < '40' ) e
      ON A.PRODUCT_NUMBER = E.PRODUCT_NUMBER = 
     AND A.DISTRICT = E.DISTRICT 
     AND E.PO_NUMBER > 899999999
WHERE A.DISTRICT = 2170 
  AND A.PRODUCT_NUMBER = 6849452
 ;

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  I would also strongly recommend that you use table abbreviations for table aliases.  They are much, much easier to follow.  Meaningless letters are, well, meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses in the last query should be fine.  Are you sure the issue is not the extra `=` rather than the parentheses?

If Tandem doesn't support the parentheses, you can replace them with a subquery:

```
FROM PRODUCT A LEFT JOIN
     WAREHOUSE B
     ON A.PRODUCT_NUMBER = B.PRODUCT_NUMBER AND
        A.DISTRICT = B.DISTRICT LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT . . .  -- whatever columns you want
         FROM PO_DETAIL E JOIN
              PO_HEADER F
              ON F.PO_NUMBER = E.PO_NUMBER ANED 
                 F.PO_NUMBER > 899999999 AND
                 F.PO_STATUS < '40'
        ) EF
        ON A.PRODUCT_NUMBER = EF.PRODUCT_NUMBER AND
           A.DISTRICT = E.DISTRICT AND
           E.PO_NUMBER > 899999999
```